# How to create a default, empty, has-one relation in Backbone-relational?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

I'm using Backbone-Relational in my project, and I have a model with another nested model in a HasOne relation.

I required the nested-model in my client-side even if it doesn't exist in my server.
If my server sends the nested modal data everything is fine.
If it doesn't, I want the HasOne relation to create an empty nested-model by default.

The only way I found to achieve this is like so:

```
parse: function(parentModelData) {
  if (!this.has('nestedModel') && !parentModelData.nestedModel) {
    parentModelData.nestedModel = {};
  }
  return parentModelData;
}
```

This is clearly messy. Is there any other simpler way? 
Thanks.

Comment: Not really, don't know what this weird syntax is but in normal JavaScript you would do `data.nested_model = data.nested_model || {}` though I am not sure that Backbone creates a model if it encounters an empty object does it?

Comment: Weird syntax is CoffeeScript.

BackboneRelational creates an empty model if you supply the parent-model with an empty hash.

Your example is missing the `@get()`, which is required if I don't want to override any existing nested-model.

Comment: I edited the code to be Javascript so more people can help :)